# search for files and create conditions using gnuplot

Tags: file, for-loop, if-statement, find, gnuplot

Tell me please how to make a script using gnuplot:

**have folder:**

`d:/data/`

in which there are files in the format

`[text1][delta=text2][text3][mac=text4].csv`

**need to create the script for all the files in the folder:**

```
for [file] of [files]
{
    if [file] content text1 == 'packets' and text4 == 'all'
    {
        set xlabel "amount" font "Calibri, 10"
    }
    else
    {
        set xlabel "size" font "Calibri, 10"
    }

    set output "d:/images/out_[file].png"
    plot [file] using ...
}
```

more simple code without conditions I could create

```
files = system("ls -1 d:/data/*.csv")
plot for [data in files] data using 1:3 with line ls 2 notitle
```

but how can I make a more complex code with the terms I can not understand :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the individual parts of the file name are delimited by an underscore, one might proceed for example as shown below. There, the scripts iterates over all files via a `do for` loop and splits each file name using Gnuplot's `strstrt` function (this might be done also with a `system` call and utilities such as `gawk/cut`, etc.). Since the `text1`, `text4` variables are strings, the comparison is then done with the `eq` operator.

```
set terminal pngcairo

files = system("ls -1 *.csv")

do for [file in files] {
  print sprintf("processing file: '%s'", file)

  j = strstrt(file, "_");
  if (j == 0) { continue; }
  text1 = file[1:j-1] #ranges are inclusive in Gnuplot

  i = strstrt(file, "mac=");
  j = strstrt(file, ".csv");

  if (i == 0 || j == 0) { continue; }

  #i+4 since we want to start after the 'mac=' delimiter
  text4 = file[i+4:j-1]; 

  if (text1 eq "packets" && text4 eq "all") {
    set xlabel "..."
  }

  set output sprintf("out_%s.png", file);
  plot file using ...
}
```